# Block about: pages in firefox

Tags: firefox

I need to make it impossible for other people, to install, remove or disable/enable addons from Firefox on an Ubuntu machine.

This would be easy if only I could block access to about:addons (and for that matter other about: pages), in such a way that they could only be unlocked by a user with sudo access; I have already tried adding:

```
"127.0.0.1   about:addons"
```

to `/etc/hosts` but that has no effect. (It can block some websites, but not about: pages).

Annoyingly, there are multiple websites telling how to do this, on windows, such as:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139522/prevent-users-from-disabling-or-uninstalling-a-firefox-addon
- https://www.ilovefreesoftware.com/11/tutorial/how-to-disable-uninstallation-firefox-extensions-group-policy.html

or more.

I have not been able to find an up to date (working) information on how to do this on Linux

To specify "other people" assume they are people with full physical access to my computer, but without root or sudo access.

Comment: Remind that it's easy for everyone who has physical access to the computer to do whatever they want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You should use FireFox's enterprise management system, where you can instruct FireFox to use a specific config file at launch which can include options to lock settings.

Once you've created the config file you should restrict write access to only the root user, but allow all users to read.

Read [this official guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Enterprise_deployment_before_60#Installation) on how to configure this.

I'm not sure on the exact key you'd need to disable add-on installation, or how to block `about:config`, you could try adding it to the blocked sites list within this config file.

Comment: This is a stupid question, but the article specifies that I need to find the folder where the firefox executable is located, and then tells where it is on windows and mac.. but I can't find it on linux, I have looked in usr/share, .local/share, .local/bin and .mozilla, but where is it?

Comment: I think it is just `/etc/firefox`.  you can use `whereis firefox` to get a rough idea of what directories relate to it.

Comment: I don't know how to add something to the blocked sites list within the configuration file, and I can't find a description on the guide on how to do so

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way, using the policies mentioned in the guides you referred to.

While Windows has a built in way to do this via the registry, the same effect can be achieved on Linux by an independent means (should work on Windows as well, if your Version doesn't have the group policies function, hello there anyone who came over from superuser or something).

Create a file named `policies.json` in `yourInstallationDirectory/distribution`. In this file you write the following:

```
{
 "policies": {
   "BlockAboutConfig": true,
   "BlockAboutAddons": true
 }
}
```

and whatever else you want blocked according to

https://mozilla.github.io/policy-templates/

The official guide detailing this (which is somehow really hard to find) is found under

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customizing-firefox-using-policiesjson

Also see the readme on the official Mozilla github:

https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/master/README.md